# Find minimum using the fminsearch of matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to get the minimum of the following function, but get and error.

I relied on: `x = fminsearch(fun,x0) starts at the point x0 and attempts to find a local minimum x of the function described in fun.` of matlab

This is how the function looks like:
1. First method

```
function [x, y] = call_function(par1, par2, par3, par4, pos1, pos2)
    x0 = [0;0;0];
    call_inner_fun = @(x)inner_fun(par1, par2, par3, par4, pos1, pos2,x);
    [solver,~] = fminsearch(call_inner_fun,x0);
    var1 = solver(1);
    var2 = solver(2);
    var3 = solver(3);

    function myFun = inner_fun(par1, par2, par3, par4, pos1, pos2,x)
        vector = [pos1(2); pos1(1); pos2(2); pos2(1)];
        b_mat= [par1, 0, 1; par2, 1, 0; par3, 0, 1; par4, 1, 0];
        myFun = (vector - b_mat*x).^2;
    end

end
```

2. Second method

```
function [x, y] = call_function(par1, par2, par3, par4, pos1, pos2)
    x0 = [0;0;0];
    vector = [pos1(2); pos1(1); pos2(2); pos2(1)];
    b_mat= [par1, 0, 1; par2, 1, 0; par3, 0, 1; par4, 1, 0];
    myFun = @(x)vector - b_mat*x;

    optimization_options = optimoptions(@lsqnonlin,'Algorithm','levenberg-marquardt','Display','off');
    solver = lsqnonlin(myFun , x0, [], [], optimization_options);
    var1 = solver(1);
    var2 = solver(2);
    var3 = solver(3);
end
```

The error occurs here `myFun = (vector - b_mat*x).^2;`
I would please like to know what I'm doing wrong in the first method.
My second question is to know, if there is a difference between both methods. Thank you in advance...

Comment: Optimizers expect their cost function to return a scalar value. Your calculation of `myFun` returns a 4 element vector.  Presumably you want `myFun = sum((vector - b_mat*x).^2);`

Comment: @PhilGoddard To be more precise, `fminsearch` requires the cost function to output a scalar, `lsqnonlin`  asks to return a vector.

Comment: The difference between the two methods becomes clear when looking at the 'Algorithm' section in the doc ([`fminsearch`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html#bvadxhn-12) vs [`lsqnonlin`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html#buul744-1)). Basically `fminsearch` does not use gradients, where `lsqnonlin` does.

Comment: @rinkert, true.  Many optimizers require a scalar (e.g. fmincon, fminunc, fminsearch) while some (e.g. fminimax, lsqnonlin) require vectors.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Should I expect the same result using any of the algorithms ?

Comment: @Kvin. In many instances they should give similar, but not identical, results. (If they were all expected to give the same result then only one of them would have been implemented.)